# How is "3 nights" calculated when using Jordan Pass?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, jordan

The official [Jordan Pass](https://www.jordanpass.jo/) offers waiving of Jordan visa fee, but only if you stay in Jordan for three consecutive nights:

> part of the pass's benefits is that it waives the visa fees (40 JDs)
>   only if you are staying 3 consecutive nights and buy it before arrival
>   to Jordan.

How do they define "night" is unclear. For example, assuming my arrival is July 1st, and I am departing on July 4th at 2am - so as long as I pass immigration after midnight on 4th, technically I am in Jordan on three nights if they look at dates. But if they consider "night" as "hotel stay in Jordan", then I am not.

How does "three consecutive nights" are calculated, as calendar dates or actual hotel stays?

**Update:** I also emailed the Jordan Pass website through their contact form asking this exact question. Here is their reply:

> Yes but please make sure not to stamp your passport before 12:01 am of July 4th, otherwise, they will ask you to pay for your visa.

This is what I expected, but not exactly matching the "full 3 nights" described on their website, so I wonder how does the Immigration applies it. Thus I will leave the question open until someone comes up with personal experience on that matter. Or until I do this myself.

Comment: Such a nice question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience it basically comes down to how many "nights" you stay in the country - where a night would basically be defined as staying in a hotel.

According to my passport stamps, I entered Jordan on the 11th of November, and left on the 13th - which would appear to be 2 nights and 3 days and thus would not qualify for the free visa.

However I actually entered just after midnight on the 11th - in effect the night of the 10th.  I stay in a hotel for 3 nights (the nights of the 10th, 11th and 12th) and then left late in the day on the 13th.  I had confirmed with the Jordan Pass staff in advance that this would be considered as 3 night and thus suitable for the free visa, and they had confirmed it would be (despite not meeting the "4 day" requirement).

I had originally be planning to arrive on the morning of the 11th (around 8am) and depart at 2:30am on the 14th (which makes this a similar situation to yours) and they confirmed that would NOT be considered 3 nights.

Comment: The "night" seem to be indeed interpreted as calendar dates, not related to times, and as confirmed by Jordan Pass website support, getting through the passport control at 12:01 next day is indeed sufficient.